# How to determine if a boost::variant variable is empty?

Tags: c++, boost, variant

I have defined a boost::variant var like this:

```
boost::variant<boost::blank, bool, int> foo;
```

This variable, when instantiated but not initialized, has a value of type `boost::blank`, because `boost::blank` is the first type passed to the templated boost::variant.

At some point, I want to know if `foo` has been initialized. I've tried this, but with no good results:

```
if (foo) //doesn't compile
if (foo != boost::blank()) //doesn't compile
if (!(foo == boost::blank())) //doesn't compile
```

I think it's worth noticing that, when `foo` has been initialized (eg., `foo = true`), it can be "reset" by doing `foo = boost::blank();`.

How can I check if `foo` has been initialized, ie, it has a different type than `boost::blank`?

Comment: `bool const is_blank = boost::get<boost::blank>(&foo)`

Comment: @PiotrS. it works but I don't quite get why. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @PiotrS.: `boost::variant<comment, answer> foo(getWhatThatShouldHaveBeen()); assert(foo.which() == 1);`

Comment: @FerranMG: Why not _read the documentation_???

Comment: @pmed it also works, but I'm concerned about a possible performance hit. As far as I know, `boost::get` performs a `static_cast` and applies a visitor if the cast is successful. Would a visitor of type `boost::blank` be so trivial that I could neglect the overhead?

Comment: @FerranMG: My answer is extremely cheap. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't _read the documentation_ because I mistakenly assumed `which` worked differently. There really is no need to be pushy. Your answer is cheap and valid, but could eventually cause problems. I'll add a comment to your answer to discuss that.

Comment: @FerranMG: I'm not being "pushy"; reading the documentation should have been your first step and I absolutely reserve the right to point that out when you're asking for free help.

Comment: @FerranMG: AFAIK static visitor in boost::variant uses an index table based on `which` for visit functions. I don't think there would be significant performance difference to check against `which()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the first type is "active", `foo.which() == 0`. Use that.

> **Returns:** The zero-based index into the set of bounded types of the contained type of `*this`. (For instance, if called on a `variant<int, std::string>` object containing a `std::string`, `which()` would return `1`.)

(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#idp288369344-bb)

Comment: This works, but could eventually be the cause of problems if ever the ordering of the types in the `boost::variant` definition changes. It will work perfectly fine practically always (more so because I'm trying to identify when the variable is of type `boost::blank`, which makes much more sense to have as the first type), but I think `boost::get<boost::blank>(&foo)` would be a more complete solution if it were as cheap as `foo.which() == 0`. Sadly, I guess I'm going to have to choose between hypothetical problems, or real overhead, so I'll probably end up using `which`.

Comment: +1 and agreed. I still showed the visitor approach in my answer, because concerns like this often stem from fear. And the fear stems from lack of experience. Visitors don't need to be intimidating :)

Answer (score 11):

You could define a visitor to detect the 'blankness':

```
struct is_blank_f : boost::static_visitor<bool> {
   bool operator()(boost::blank) const { return true; }

   template<typename T>
   bool operator()(T const&) const { return false; }
};
```

Use it like so:

```
bool is_blank(my_variant const& v) {
   return boost::apply_visitor(is_blank_f(), v);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because it's complete, but for my use case I'll need to avoid the overhead that calling a visitor will add. Thanks for it, though.

Comment: @FerranMG my bet: it won't add overhead. Compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Looks like the `0==which()` check wins anyways, guessing from the generated assembly (clang 3.6 and gcc 5.x). Tried to benchmark but it's hard to get useful measurements on the `which()` check: https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius/issues/20